# Generate string by switching ASCII code (extended)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a list of strings that were "encrypted" with a simple char code switching. To make them readable I need to increase each character code by 7. The problem is that those codes can be above 127 (extended ASCII). I'm iterating each seed string and trying to produce a new string like this

```
string result = "";
for(std::string::iterator it = myEncryptedWord.begin(); it != myEncryptedWord.end(); ++it) 
{
   unsigned char myC = *it;
   result+= char(myC+7);
}
```

It does not work for codes above 127 (characters like áóõã...). Needless to say that I can't control the original string list and change this poor "encryption".

Comment: Why does it not work? I don't see a problem with it

Comment: What should it return for decoding 127?

Comment: @sagi should show a \ (127+7 = 134)

Comment: @MiguelE Your code produces that value. What character it will show depends on the character encoding that the outputting terminal uses and whether that coincides with the encoding you have in mind.

Comment: 134 is not the decimal representation of \. It's the octavian one. 134 is indeed nothing in the ASCII table.. you should define your problem better.

Comment: @MiguelE \ is 92 in ASCII, how did you arrive at 134? There's no such thing as "extended" ASCII in the first place. Whatever is beyond 127 purely depends on locale and cannot be relied upon.